# No GL context; create a Window first

Tags: google-colaboratory, openai-gym, stable-baselines

When I ran the Stable Baselines3 RL Colab Notebooks, an error occurred.
[stable_baselines_getting_started.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/github/Stable-Baselines-Team/rl-colab-notebooks/blob/sb3/stable_baselines_getting_started.ipynb#scrollTo=iATu7AiyMQW2)

```
record_video('CartPole-v1', model, video_length=500, prefix='ppo-cartpole')
```

```
GLException                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-e858dbb4fbff> in <module>
----> 1 record_video('CartPole-v1', model, video_length=500, prefix='ppo-cartpole')

18 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyglet/gl/lib.py in errcheck(result, func, arguments)
    100     context = gl.current_context
    101     if not context:
--> 102         raise GLException('No GL context; create a Window first')
    103     if not context._gl_begin:
    104         error = gl.glGetError()

GLException: No GL context; create a Window first
```

Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Run nvidia-xconfig and it'll make the X config file for you

In the notebook, make this cell and run it:

`!nvidia-xconfig`